# How to customize "my own price string" WooCommerce Composite products

Tags: php, wordpress, composite, price

I got this snippet from WooCommerce where I can now add my own price string for each composite product in back-end.

[image]

I have added, as I wanted to have it: "From: € 887 incl. tax". This shall be fixed, no link to the database but the style needs to sync with the UX Flatsome theme I'm using where "From:" shall be light gray, "€ 887" no changes and "incl. tax" smaller but black and normal style, only smaller than "€ 887". The solution will then help me to let this fixed "text" to look just like the theme does with its "From: € xxx incl. tax" that normally appears.

Thanks for your understanding and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the style by adding a style.css to your theme. What CSS to use depends on your theme. Use Chrome right click at the object. See the CSS part and edit it to your needs (you can see it changing). If satisfied, copy the part to your style.css and upload it to your theme root path.